In SCSS, is it possible to make a variable value that response to the responsive design?
So i have the following styling code:

@mixin smaller-than($breakpoint) {
  @media (max-width: $breakpoint) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin larger-than($breakpoint) {
  @media (min-width: $breakpoint) {
    @content;
  }
}

.header{
   height: 60px;
   @include larger-than($breakpoint-md){
       height: 80px;
   }
   @include larger-than($breakpoint-xl){
       height: 120px;
   }
}
.content{
   height: calc(100vh - 60px);
   @include larger-than($breakpoint-md){
       height: calc(100vh - 80px);
   }
   @include larger-than($breakpoint-xl){
       height: calc(100vh - 120px);
   }
}
.spacer {
   padding-top: 60px;
   @include larger-than($breakpoint-md){
       padding-top: 80px;
   }
   @include larger-than($breakpoint-xl){
       padding-top: 120px;
   }
}

is there a way in SCSS so that i can achieve it with some minimal code and guaranteed sync between the value? maybe i am thinking on something like this:
function header-height(){
   return 60px;
   @include larger-than($breakpoint-md){
       return 80px;
   }
   @include larger-than($breakpoint-xl){
       return 120px;
   }
    
}

.header {
   height: header-height();
}
.content {
   height: calc(100vh - header-height());
}
.spacer {
   padding-top: header-height();
}


Could you share the larger-than mixen?

@YuvarajM i updated the source code

SCSS cannot know anything about runtime. It is a compiled language.

@connexo is correct

@connexo is it not possible to create some kind of like template or macro code?

If you want an easier way to make responsive attributes using scss, I have a mixin that does some of what you want, but may not be perfect for you. Still wanted to put it here just in case :)
@mixin responsive_attribute($attr, $breakpoints) {
    @each $func, $breakpoint, $value in $breakpoints {
        @if $func == smaller-than {
            @media (max-width: $breakpoint) {
                #{$attr}: $value;
            }
        }
        @else if $func == larger-than {
            @media (min-width: $breakpoint) {
                #{$attr}: $value;
            }
        }
    }
}

.header {
    height: 60px;
    @include responsive_attribute("height", (
        smaller-than 320px 80px,
        larger-than 1000px 120px
    ));
}

The actual mixin I use is a little more declarative imo, but is against scss mixin norms so I wanted to give you a more basic one. But if you want the mixin I use, it is more-or-less the one below:
@mixin responsive_attribute($attr, $breakpoints) {
    @each $func, $breakpoint, $_, $value in $breakpoints {
        @if $func == default {
            #{$attr}: $breakpoint;
        }
        @else if $func == smaller-than {
            @media (max-width: $breakpoint) {
                #{$attr}: $value;
            }
        }
        @else if $func == larger-than {
            @media (min-width: $breakpoint) {
                #{$attr}: $value;
            }
        }
    }
}

.header {
    @include responsive_attribute("height", (
        default 60px,
        smaller-than 320px then 80px,
        larger-than 1000px then 120px
    ));
}


no, the point is i want a same value to be defined once and being used in multiple attributes

Do you want these to be variables or would it be okay for them to just be in the scope of the mixin? If its the latter, then you can easily put that in the mixin, although it could get a little more complex. I'll update my answer with an example of what this could look like

breakpoints value are fixed, the only thing that is different only the attribute that will be used, such as height, max-height, etc
